# Efficient way of deleting rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
186740210700000000 | 1859-10-9 03:00:00 | SRID=4326;POINT(134.50 -37.50) | 5 | E178548E101850
183130210700000000 | 1860-10-9 11:00:00 | SRID=4326;POINT(133.50 -38.50) | 5 | E178548E101850
183130210700000001 | 1859-10-9 15:00:00 | SRID=4326;POINT(133.50 -38.50) | 5 | E178548E101850
183120210700000000 | 1859-10-9 19:00:00 | SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -38.50) | 5 | E178548E101850
179520210700000000 | 1860-10-9 23:00:00 | SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -39.50) | 5 | E178548E101850
179520210800000000 | 1859-10-10 03:00:00 | SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -39.50) | 5 | E178548E101850
```

What I would like to do is to cancels those row where for example the year is `1860` but then restoring the appearance of the dataframe as the one above. Which is the best way?

Many thanks

Comment: Are the columns delineated by the | character? If it's already in a data frame, I think you can easily use a function to extract the year from the POSIX datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for a pattern in the second column using `grepl`:

```
dat[!grepl("1860", dat[ , 2]), ]
```

This will exclude all rows in which `1860` can be found in column 2.

The result:

```
            V1                    V2                               V3 V4              V5
1 1.867402e+17   1859-10-9 03:00:00   SRID=4326;POINT(134.50 -37.50)   5  E178548E101850
3 1.831302e+17   1859-10-9 15:00:00   SRID=4326;POINT(133.50 -38.50)   5  E178548E101850
4 1.831202e+17   1859-10-9 19:00:00   SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -38.50)   5  E178548E101850
6 1.795202e+17  1859-10-10 03:00:00   SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -39.50)   5  E178548E101850
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `POSIX` date/time class, as suggested by @TARehman:

```
df[,2] <- as.POSIXct(df[,2], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
(df[as.POSIXlt(df[,2])$year != 1860 - 1900,])
#             V1                  V2                               V3 V4              V5
# 1 1.867402e+17 1859-10-09 03:00:00  SRID=4326;POINT(134.50 -37.50)   5  E178548E101850
# 3 1.831302e+17 1859-10-09 15:00:00  SRID=4326;POINT(133.50 -38.50)   5  E178548E101850
# 4 1.831202e+17 1859-10-09 19:00:00  SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -38.50)   5  E178548E101850
# 6 1.795202e+17 1859-10-10 03:00:00  SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -39.50)   5  E178548E101850


df[,1] <- format(df[,1], scientific=F)
cat(paste(apply(df, 1, paste, collapse=" | "), collapse="\n"))
# 186740210700000000 | 1859-10-09 03:00:00 |  SRID=4326;POINT(134.50 -37.50)  | 5 |  E178548E101850
# 183130210700000000 | 1860-10-09 11:00:00 |  SRID=4326;POINT(133.50 -38.50)  | 5 |  E178548E101850
# 183130210700000000 | 1859-10-09 15:00:00 |  SRID=4326;POINT(133.50 -38.50)  | 5 |  E178548E101850
# 183120210700000000 | 1859-10-09 19:00:00 |  SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -38.50)  | 5 |  E178548E101850
# 179520210700000000 | 1860-10-09 23:00:00 |  SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -39.50)  | 5 |  E178548E101850
# 179520210800000000 | 1859-10-10 03:00:00 |  SRID=4326;POINT(132.50 -39.50)  | 5 |  E178548E101850
```